# Delete Messenger conversations via API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

If one use Messenger API (Messenger Platform, with webhook) to receive and answer Messenger messages via another tool (contact center tool or a bot).

- How can you then delete the messages or conversations from the facebook page inbox?

I have this documentation, that says delete is not supported.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v18.0/conversation

Please note, I understand of course that the conversation cannot be deleted from the facebook-system in general, as it still need to be in the users account.

- I also wonder if it is posible to just deactivate inbox completely for a facebook page if the business use a third party tool to handle conversations?
- Could it be that a large business can be whitelisted for delete?

Thanks if anyone can provide some input:)